# How to draw the bounds of a model around the 1:1 line

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, data-visualization

I have a regression model and I want to plot the measured values versus the predicted values. I have seen that in many papers researchers superimpose a 1:1 line with a ± bounds of the model shown. My question is how these bounds are calculated. please see the figure below as an example.
[image]

Comment: Note that without a specific reference we can't be sure what a particular author might have done in some instance (and even with a reference it won't necessarily be possible to tell).  It may be possible to suggest some way to do it but it won't necessarily be what you see done in a particular paper.

Comment: @Glen Agreed--and it's important to know the details of this "regression model"--but we can deduce quite a bit from the plot. The bounding lines are evidently of reciprocal slopes (notice the upper one is a little further from the main diagonal than the lower one is) and also pass through the origin. This suggests they are based on a univariate analysis of either $y/x$ or (more likely) $\log(y/x)$. The 68-95-99.7 rule, which will be very accurate here, indicates they are placed somewhere around $\pm 1\sigma$ to $\pm 1.5\sigma$--there are too many overplotted points to make a precise estimate.

Comment: so what you are saying is that I should calculate log(y/x) and get the σ?